# How to install custom armabi image into new emulator device

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator, armv7, android-device-manager

I want to create an emulator device with armabi-v7a and android 13 (SDK 33). However the Android Studio device manager doesn't let me choose that architecture.

[image: recommended]

[image: arm images]

[image: other images]

I managed to download the system image from internet and place it into the same Library folder (MacOs) but the option still doesn't appear when I restart AS and try to choose the image.

[image]

Is there a step I'm missing to be able to use this architecture on the emulator?

I only see v7a alternatives down bellow to APi 24 which won't work for me.

[image]

Comment: Just making sure you are aware of: https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2020/03/run-arm-apps-on-android-emulator.html and while you could build your own image: https://source.android.com/docs/setup/create/avd performance of QEMU may be suspect.

Comment: Yeah It seems that mac m1 cannot install arm v7a images, and with other intel machines I got a very unstable emulator.